# Unable to use AWS to communicate with my android mobile application

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

**Goal:**
I need to create an android mobile application that is able to communicate with an algorithm that my team will be creating.

**Comments:**
I have basically finished the android mobile application. It just needs to now link up with whatever (I guess a server or instance) is running the algorithm. The algorithm would be best if it was written in R, but it can be rewritten in Java if necessary. I have looked into trying to create an API of some sort. I have also looked into using firebase or AWS (Amazon Web Services).

I have devoted a lot of time on AWS, specifically their EC2 free tier. I have tried creating an EC2 instance and then putting Java code on it. I was not only unable to figure out how to put the code on it, but also how I would call the code from my app. I looked into Beanstalk, but it seems to be more for web applications. I also looked into Lambda functions but those seem overly complex for what I am trying to do.

**Problem:**
The AWS description of how to set up an EC2 instance, put code onto it, and then call the code from my android app has been a nightmare to understand and implement. It might honestly just be the fact that I am very new to working with backend processes, but I can't seem to figure out any of this out. So far on AWS I have only created an account and used Amazon Cognito to sign-in users. I need help understanding how it works, if it is the best option for my project, and how I can integrate it into my mobile application.

Comment: Do you know if the "algorithm" is a rest API or something else?

Comment: @Steve101 It will be a rest API. My understanding is that I will send the algorithm two variables. The algorithm will use those variables and return a list of results.